# Passing XMl to the Jaxb Unmarshaller in form of String

Tags: jaxb

I have a Customer class and also an related xml file to it .

```
            File file = new File("D:\\TestingData\\customer.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer data = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

I need to place the customer.xml file in an external location . (D:\TestingData\customer.xml)

My question is that can i supply the xml file as part of String to the unmarshall Method ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can i supply the xml file as part of String

Yes, you just need to wrap it in a `StringReader`.

```java
String xml = "<foo><bar>Hello World</bar></foo>";
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unnmarshal(reader);
```